# Upload Image from storage to FTP in android

Tags: android, json, ftp

I want to upload image from storage to FTP using json and save the name of the image into the database in android. 
If using simpleftp, how can i import the library in android studio, what should  I compile in gradle build? 
I'm using android studio.
Can anyone give the reference about how to do it? Please give me your advice about it. Thank you

Comment: what on earth is "FTP using json"?

Comment: can u give me the references about how to do ftp uploading? @zapl